# How to setup .htaccess to rewrite to a different folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm moving my site to a new host but I need to have my current server continue to handle requests (not all files can be moved to the new server).
So I added a parked domain to my old server (old.mydomain.com) and I want all requests to it to be written to the files from the old site.

My old site (mydomain.com) was hosted internally in a folder (`/public_html/mydomain/`) and I want all requests to old.mydomain.com to be rewritten to the same folder.
So if `mydomain.com/blog` was internally at `/public_html/mydomain/blog`, I now want `old.mydomain.com/blog` also to reach `/public_html/mydomain/blog`.

Here is the .htaccess that I'm trying to use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old\.mydomain\.com/*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mydomain/$1 [NC,L]
```

But for some reason as soon as I add the `$1` in the rewrite rule I get an internal error.

Any ideas?

Comment: This probably isn't the cause of your error, but I don't think you want the `/*` on the end of your RewriteCond - HTTP_HOST will only contain the hostname, not the entire URL

Comment: Off topic.  Probably belongs on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 0):

Configure this as a separate vhost called `old.mydomain.com` and ensure it comes before `*.mydomain.com` in your vhost definitions (i.e. higher in `vhosts.conf`). Give `old.mydomain.com` the same DocumentRoot as your previous domain had.

`.htaccess` is the most processor intensive way to serve a webpage, and should only be used there are no other options available.

Comment: I'm on a shared host so I don't have access to vhosts.conf

Answer (score 0):

Please try to fix your .htaccess config as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public_html/mydomain/$1 [NC,L]
```